# How to resolve merge conflicts in a branch without actually merging?

Tags: git

I have 3 branches: master, develop, and hotfix-12345.

hotfix-12345 is branched off of master, but needs to be merged into develop.

So I

```
git checkout develop

git merge --no-ff hotfix-12345
```

And my merge conflicts appear. Okay, so (in Visual Studio Code) I "*Accept Incoming Changes*" for the files that have conflicts, and save. But I'm on develop, so these changes are only fixed in develop, not the hotfix branch, and I can't push the develop branch, it has to be the hotfix branch. So trying to merge my local `hotfix-12345` into `origin develop` will still give merge conflicts.

If try to merge the reverse (develop into hotfix-12345), unstage everything except the merge conflict files, resolve the conflicts and save them, they don't appear in `git status` as modified files.

How do I find the merge conflcits in `hotfix-12345` with `develop` & resolve them without actually merging develop into `hotfix-12345` ?

Comment: Did you consider cherry-picking instead?

Comment: Why do you want to push resolved conflicts between hotfix and develop back to hotfix if hotfix is branched off of master? It would seem that once you've made the fix off master, merged the hotfix back into master, and then merged hotfix (or master) into develop and resolved the conflicts then you should be good to go. Look up gitflow and how hotfix branches are typically resolved into master and develop.

Comment: @John I've looked up various articles and I get how it's supposed to look in the end, but I can't get to that process. The end result is supposed to be: Diff between hotfix <-> master = only the changes in hotfix, since hotfix is branched off master. Diff between hotfix and develop <-> = commits currently in develop that haven't pushed live onto master & hotfix branch changes. But I don't know how to resolve the conflicts in hotfix so that the only changes between hotfix and master are the hotfix + merge conflict resolution && the changes between dev && hotfix are everything in dev  + hotfix.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I find the merge conflcits in hotfix-12345 with develop & resolve them without actually merging develop into hotfix-12345 ?

One possibility would be to *rebase* the `hotfix` branch on top of `origin/develop`: you can resolve conflict there, and then revert some of the origin/develop changes you do not want in `hotfix`.
Once that selection is done, you can push `hotfix`, while develop remains local and untouched.

```
git checkout hotfix
git rebase origin/develop
git rebase
```